# Why my API request does not work?

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am trying to get information of specific topic through the Wikipedia json API, however, when I click the button, nothing happen. Console does not report any problems. Is it related to **CORS** problems?

```
function buttonClick() {
let request = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=search&prop=pageimages|extracts&pilimit=max&exintro&explaintext&exsentences=1&exlimit=max&gsrsearch=cream&&callback=?";

  request.open("GET", url, false);
  request.onload = function() {
    let data = JSON.parse(this.response);

    document.write(data);
 };
 request.send;
};
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Explain "not working." Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Maybe you should try the Fetch API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: 1/ Send need `()` 2/ Your url is malformed: `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&exlimit=max&format=json&exsentences=1&origin=*&exintro=&explaintext=&generator=search&gsrlimit=10&gsrsearch=ntm` is working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using the Fetch API, it's more "modern" and has better support for Promises.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

To make a cors request to wikipedia, add `origin=*` to the query and remove the `callback=?` part from it.

```
let url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?origin=*&format=json&action=query&generator=search&prop=pageimages|extracts&pilimit=max&exintro&explaintext&exsentences=1&exlimit=max&gsrsearch=cream';

fetch(url).then(v => v.json()).then(v => console.log(v));
```

Comment: I made a slight edit to your answer because the question was already closed.

Comment: np thanks that looks good